# Local Development, Apache vs Developer - file permissions

Tags: apache, development-environment, file-permissions

I am interested in setting up a local php testing / development environment using the lamp stack.
I would like to use the php plugin for eclipse (I typically work with java and am very familiar with eclipse).

- First of all, is it proper practice to develop my site locally directly within the apache /var/www directory?
- If this is ok, can somebody describe how to properly set the permissions of the www directory so that eclipse (not being run as root) has access to read/modify php files within that directory?

This is strictly for local development so I assume security isn't as high of an issue.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter, I personally placed it in /var/www/ and put it under the www-data group, and placed my username into the www-data group.

You add yourself into the group with:

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data <username>
```

Change the group to www-data just in case you haven't:

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www
```

Get new files to inherit the permissions (750)

```
sudo chmod -R 2750 www-data /var/www
```

Some people prefer to put it in /home/username/www/ which would be easier.

Comment: so your saying you created a www-data directory within /var/www?

also, how would I go about putting it in /home/username/www/? would the php files get picked up here by the php interpreter still?

Comment: Nope, he is making you a member of the "apache group (www-data)" and then giving the `/var/www` directory the proper ownership and permissions for you to work as a member of the `www-data` group.

Comment: You'll also need to make sure Apache runs as a user in this group.

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer to put it somewhere else, like your Eclipse workspace directory, you can change Apache's DocumentRoot (or create a VirtualHost with a different DocumentRoot). Edit Apache's httpd.conf file, and add this at the end:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mytestserver.localhost
  DocumentRoot /path/to/project/dir
</VirtualHost>
```

The *s can be left as-is; that means they will work regardless of your IP address.

The ServerName can be anything you want, as long as you add a corresponding entry in your /etc/hosts file, e.g.:

```
127.0.0.1 mytestserver.localhost
```

I often make all my local servers end in ".localhost", just as a convention.

Finally, restart Apache. Then you can access the server at http://mytestserver.localhost. Repeat as necessary to use multiple virtual hosts, each pointing to a different project.

As long as the files can be read by everyone, which is usually the default, you should be fine.

Comment: I would also combine this with KahWee's idea for making your self apart of the www-data group. This way you don't need to have such relaxed permissions on the directory.

Comment: this seems like exactly what I need.  pardon my ignorance but could you elaborate on how I would fill this in exactly assuming I am developing locally (i.e. what would I fill in for NameVirtualHost etc.)? thanks

Comment: i guess what i am asking is with that virtual host, how would i access the files in a web browser? before I would just go to http://localhost/, but now what?

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible to work on your site directly in your server's /var/www/ directory.  however, it's probably better practice to setup a local environment (using something like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)) to edit your website on a development machine and then upload it to your live server when it's ready.  that way you don't introduce any bugs or errors into the live site temporarily.